# Can Jade render closing tags invalidly?

Tags: node.js, pug

I have an jade page. 1/10 times, (it's almost hard to repro), the closing HTML tag is rendered as follows:

```
</body> html></
```

It looks like the two parts of the html tag are not in the right order. I'm using Jade 1.1.5, though it's not the latest version, I have never seen this issue before.

Comment: That seems extremely unlikely to me. Do you have a code sample?

Comment: I guess I could give a code sample but It's simply a body tag within an html tag.